# Shiny App with dichromat_pal filter is not working

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following code that creates a Shiny App that allows a user to toggle back and forth between 2 versions of a graph (one that isn't good, and one that is optimized). I need the app to be able to test each of them (depending on what one is selected) against the colorblind palettes in dichromat.

This code pulls the app up, and allows me to toggle between the two plots, but when I try selecting the colorblind type to filter it I get the following error:

`Warning: Error in : 'dichromat_pal' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dichromat'`

I have uninstalled and reinstalled `dichromat`, I have double-checked that it is loaded, and I have restarted R multiple times trying to fix this. I'm thinking there must be something wrong with my code.

```
library(shiny)
library(dichromat)
library(ggplot2)


# Define the UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Graphic Optimization"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      3,
      selectInput(
        "image_name", "Image:",
        c(
          "Original" = "original",
          "Improved" = "improved"
        )
      ),
      selectInput(
        "color_blind_type", "Type of ColorBlindness:",
        c(
          "Normal", "Deutan", "Protan", "Tritan"
        )
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot"),
      plotOutput("filtered_plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define the server
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- read.csv("badgraph.csv")
  
  filtered_colors <- reactive({
    switch(input$color_blind_type,
           "Normal" = NULL,
           "Deutan" = dichromat::dichromat_pal("deutan")(length(unique(data$Race.Sex))),
           "Protan" = dichromat::dichromat_pal("protan")(length(unique(data$Race.Sex))),
           "Tritan" = dichromat::dichromat_pal("tritan")(length(unique(data$Race.Sex)))
    )
  })
  
  # Define the plot
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    data$Mth.Yr <- as.Date(paste(data$Mth.Yr, "-01", sep = ""))
    if (input$image_name == "original") {
      original_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Mth.Yr, y = Rate, group = Race.Sex, color = Race.Sex)) +
        geom_line(size = 1) +
        scale_color_manual(
          values =
            c(
              "#6EAA75", "#C9C9C9", "#000000", "#5B5B5B", "#FFC6FF",
              "#AD8BC9", "#619CFF", "#F9A26C", "#FF6161",
              "#FFBE61"
            )
        ) +
        labs(
          x = "Month/Year", y = "Unemployment Rate",
          title = "Unemployment Rates by Race and Sex",
          subtitle = "Groups not defined as 16-19, are all adults 20+"
        ) +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "lines"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = 7, hjust = 1)
        )
      
      if (!is.null(input$color_blind_type)) {
        if (input$color_blind_type == "Normal") {
          original_plot <- original_plot
        } else {
          original_plot <- original_plot + scale_color_manual(values = filtered_colors())
        }
      }
      
      original_plot
      
    } else {
      data$Mth.Yr <- as.Date(paste(data$Mth.Yr, "-01", sep = ""))
      
      improved_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = Mth.Yr, y = Rate,
                                             group = Race.Sex, color = Race.Sex,
                                             linetype = Race.Sex)) +
        geom_line(aes(size = Race.Sex)) +
        scale_size_manual(values = c(1, 1.25, 1, 1, 1.25, 1, 2, 1, 1.25, 1)) +
        scale_color_manual(
          values =
            c(
              "#2c7bb6", "#2c7bb6", "#2c7bb6", "#abd9e9", "#abd9e9",
              "#abd9e9", "#d7191c", "#fdae61", "#fdae61",
              "#fdae61"
            )
        ) +
        scale_linetype_manual(
          values = c("solid", "dotdash", "dashed", "solid", "dotdash", "dashed",
                     "solid", "solid", "dotdash", "dashed")
        ) +
        labs(
          x = "Month/Year", y = "Unemployment Rate",
          title = "Unemployment Rates by Race and Sex",
          subtitle = "Groups not defined as 16-19, are all adults 20+"
        ) +
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month") +
        theme_bw() +
        theme(
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "lines"),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size = 7, hjust = 1)
      )
      
      if (!is.null(input$color_blind_type)) {
        if (input$color_blind_type == "Normal") {
          improved_plot <- improved_plot
        } else {
          improved_plot <- improved_plot + scale_color_manual(values = filtered_colors())
        }
      }
      
      improved_plot
    }
  })
  
}
    
# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You could check whether package {scales} (which provides dichromat_pal) is installed and up to date.

Comment: We would need some data to check, like `dput(head(data))`.